# How to use Laravel validation with REACT, Check validation after each field change (Best Way)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, validation

Previously as I have worked in Laravel. There is this plugin [JsValidation Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation)

Which provides a very good experience of validation to users.

after each form field changes, it calls the API to validate the data, then it shows the error below the field if there is any error, and removes the error when that field validates.

Currently, I'm using **REACT** for the frontend and **Laravel** for the backend.

I needed the same experience for my users as the above plugin in react.

---

1. Show errors for fields ✅(This is done)
2. validate form fields after each field changes and remove the current error for that field, if there is one on a previously done validation request. (I'm seeking help for this one)

---

I was thinking to add a field called `validation_request = true` in my post request and then only validate fields not create/update the record in database.

I just want  to check the `validation_request` field after my form fields validates & then return the response back to the client and don't save/update any record. But couldn't achieve this yet.

Comment: So you can attach keypress or onblur events and call API in these listener callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I can use onBlur event to call the api to check validation, but the barrier for me is the laravel part. 
I don't want to create or update the record once the validation passed.
suppose there are 4 form fields. 2 out of 4 form fields got some error.
I fixed the first error for that field and then onblur event api should be called, to validate the new form data, then it removes the only error for first error & let it show the remaining errors.
I want this kind of experience.

Comment: Refer doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation